# Is $Y=aX^b\cdot\exp(X)$ a rational or exponential function?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, rational-functions

Is $Y=aX^b\cdot\exp(X)$ a rational or exponential function?

$Y$ and $X$ are real variables, $a$ and $b$ are parameters.

Someone said this is a product of polynomial and exponential function.

Do we have a name for this function?

Comment: What is the domain/range of the function? $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? Calling something “variables” is not specific enough at this point!

Comment: This is a product of a power function (a monomial polynomial function) and an exponential function, and unless $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, this is neither rational nor exponential.

Comment: Do we have a definite name for this function?

Comment: This is neither, a rational function has the property that it is regular function on a sphere, and an exponential has the property that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, and your function has neither.

Comment: Can we call this a nonlinear function?

Comment: You can, but this would not _really_ help categorizing this. There is no category for every kind of function, obviously.

Comment: I guess transcendental function is a good name.

Comment: Oh, jo wehler, we find the answer at the same time. Many THANKS for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $$f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R, f(x):= ax^b\cdot\exp(x)$$ extends to a holomorphic function on the complex plane

$$F: \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C, F(z):= az^b\cdot\exp(z).$$

Global holomorphic functions are named entire functions. An entire function which is not a polynomial is named a *transcendental* function. As a consequence, the function $F$ is transcendental. The crucial point is: A polynomial function extends to a holomorphic map $S^2 \longrightarrow S^2$ on the Riemann sphere $S^2$, while a transcendental functions does not.